# create as many new columns as there are months and fill them by sum of quantity

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have these data :

| Date | Item | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 | A | 30 |
| 2022-01-01 | B | 40 |
| 2022-02-01 | A | 20 |
| 2022-02-01 | C | 10 |

I would like to create as many new columns as there are months and sum the qty group by Month and by item like this :

| Item | JAN | FEB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 40 | 20 |
| B | 40 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 10 |

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: To support a variable number of month columns, you will need dynamic SQL, which means some SQL scripting work would be needed.  Also, could your data set ever have more than one year, and, if so, could the same month be reported twice in different years?

Comment: yes that's why i must use prefix with year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed need scripting for dynamic range of Month and year of data.

With the sample you have provided, you can achive by restricting two month 'January2022' and 'Febuary2022' as:

```
with sample_data as (
  select '2022-01-01' as Date ,'A' as Item,10 as Qty union all
select '2022-01-01','A',30 union all
select '2022-01-01','B',40 union all
select '2022-02-01','A',20 union all
select  '2022-02-01','C',10)

select * from(
select  format_date('%B%Y', date(Date)) Month,Item,Qty from sample_data ) pivot(sum(Qty)  for Month in ('January2022','February2022')
)


[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsYLd.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Actually, i have more than two month, this will lead to change monthly

Answer (score 0):

```
execute immediate (             
  select '''
    select * 
    from (select item, qty, date from table)
    pivot(sum(qty) for date in ("''' ||  string_agg(distinct CAST(date AS STRING), '", "' order by CAST(date AS STRING))  || '''"))
  '''
  from table

);
```